# Create option for custom posts types

Tags: custom-post-types, parameter

I'd like to add options to a custom post type and I have no idea how to deal with it.
Options should be treated as parameters for my custom post type. For instance I'll get a "Plublic / private" flag which will allow some content of my post type to be readable or not.

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use post meta to accomplish your goal depending on what you are doing and how you want to do it. [This page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) from the Codex provides lots of good info about it.